# jhipster cannot run on docker and local computer

Tags: jhipster

I followed all the steps here: https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/

1. for the local configuration, the jhipster was successfully built but didn't run on port 8080. **This is the error:**

`2020-05-06 08:11:56.212  WARN 521 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JHipsterHealthIndicatorConfiguration' defined in file [/home/jhipster/app/target/classes/com/kschain/app/config/metrics/JHipsterHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
2020-05-06 08:11:58.253 ERROR 521 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed`

**and this is what I got after all the steps are done**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-06T08:11:58Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**2. The same problem occurred with the docker image**

```
 `2020-05-06 08:16:58.253 ERROR 521 --- [  restartedMain]
 o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed`

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-06T08:18:58Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
root@e8220a295cf8:/home/jhipster/app#
```

**what's wrong?**

Comment: Can you provide some more informations? How do you start your docker images in src/main/docker? What does docker logs [your-container id] say?

Comment: docker image was well pulled and started as mentioned on the website, the problem now is the generated application within the docker fails to launch the client part after running `sudo ./mvnw`. the building shows `BUILD SUCCESS ` but nothing is up and running in the browser on port 8080

Comment: Could you edit your question to paste the logs before "Application run failed" message?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou done

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the logs:

> Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042

You probably forgot to start Cassandra as explained in your project's generated README.md:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/cassandra.yml up -d
```

Comment: I did it but I don't know why this error keeps showing up. I tried even to start my pre-installed Cassandra DB, It cannot connect to it either

Comment: it's working now :) I had to uninstall everything and start from the beginning